# What is best formula style to write of statistical results in a scientific or medical paper?

Tags: notation

I have written a dozen scientific papers and posters about medical trials and psychological trials with a lot of statistical analysis, and a common question "perturbed my certainties":

> How do I write statistical significance so that it is easy to read, and avoids repetition and panegyric?

Generally speaking the most accepted formula is

$$F(n,m) =f,\ p\lt 0.01$$

or

$$t(n) =t,\ p\lt 0.001$$

or (Holm-Sidak)

$$\alpha(n,m) =t,\ p\lt 0.001$$

or

$$ F(n,m) =f,\ p=0.69$$

when there are 2 or 3 groups, I used

$$F_{g1-g2}(n,m) =f,\ p_{g1-g2}=0.69,\ F_{g1-g3}(n,m) =f,\ p_{g1-g3}=0.69 \ldots\ .$$

My questions are

1. How to write formally correct and compact formula?
2. How to write formally correct repeated analysis vs group analysis?
3. How to highlight in formula the covariate variable?
4. How to write correlation?

Comment: This question is better suited for [Cross Validated](http://statistics.stackexchange.com), our sister statistics SE site. I will therefore migrate the question over there.

Comment: IMHO, such hieroglyphs have a better place in a table, rather than in some text.

Comment: Why does $t$ have two subscripts? What statistic is this?

Comment: yes sorry just a typos